# Change parameters at each step

Tags: java, spring-batch

Here is my Configuration:

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<PriceResponseObject> reader(Environment environment, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        return new RestReader(restTemplate);
    }

    //Processor...

    //Writer...

    @Bean
    Step firstStep(ItemReader<PriceResponseObject> reader,
                         ItemProcessor<PriceResponseObject, PriceEntity> processor,
                         ItemWriter<PriceEntity> writer,
                         StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("firstStep")
                .<PriceResponseObject, PriceEntity>chunk(1)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Step secondStep(ItemReader<PriceResponseObject> reader,
                  ItemProcessor<PriceResponseObject, PriceEntity> processor,
                  ItemWriter<PriceEntity> writer,
                  StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        //Almost the same 
    }

    @Bean
    Job btcJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                       @Qualifier("firstStep") Step fS,
                       @Qualifier("secondStep") Step sndS) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(fS)
                .next(sndS)
                .build();
    }
```

But I would to pass an argument from each step to my reader.
This argument will change depending on which step the job is. I really don't know how to do so.

Comment: What is the argument?

Comment: It's a String that changes for each step.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: If its a string then you can set the string value as system property using System.setProperty("name", value) @AfterStep and the use System.getProperty in your reader if the value of the string depends on the step.